AWS cfn-lint expects * when Fn::Sub is resolved for Principal
When upgrading cfn-lint, I got a new type of warning that took me some time to understand. The error message was:
W1031 '*' was expected when 'Fn::Sub' is resolved
The linting was for a AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
          - Sid: AllowAthenaAndQuickSight
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/aws-quicksight-service-role-v0'
            Action:
              - s3:ListBucket
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource:
              - Fn::Sub: 'arn:aws:s3:::${SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME}'
              - Fn::Sub: 'arn:aws:s3:::${SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME}/*'


A valid statement would be Principal: '*' but that would affect security in a negative way. This is however the message from the cfn-linter.
The right solution is that Principal field must also specify the type of principal, if for example AWS, Service, Federated etc. The different types of Principals are documented in the reference for Policies Elements.
The correct syntax in this example (with an AWS Role as Principal) would be:
Principal:
  {
    'AWS': !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/aws-quicksight-service-role-v0',
  }


A better error message would perhaps have been:
W1031 '*' or a valid Principal JSON object was expected when 'Fn::Sub' is resolved
